# Ember Data cache find previous/next record

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Using Ember Inspector, I can see all records nicely sitting in the cache. Using `peekRecord` I can get a record from the cache. Is there an elegant way I can get the previous/next record `id` if it exists in the cache, without a request to the server?

Otherwise I'd need to do something like this:

```
model(params) {
    return {
        item        : this.get('store').findRecord('item', params.item_id, {reload: false, backgroundReload: false}),
        currId      : params.item_id,
        prevId      : this.get('store').peekAll('item').reduce((previousValue, item, index, enumerable) => {
            var found = found || false;
            if (item.id == params.item_id) found = true;
            if (found) return previousValue;
            else return item.id;
        }, false),
        nextId      : this.get('store').peekAll('item').reduce((previousValue, item, index, enumerable) => {
            var found = found || false;
            if (found === 2) return previousValue;
            if (found === 1) found = 2;
            if (found === true) found = 1;
            if (item.id == params.item_id) found = true;
            return item.id;
        }, false)
    };
}
```

(This is a stub. I know `nextId` only works when there are at least two records after the queried one.)

Unelegant, overhead-heavy (no break), and no verification (yet, before I continue down this path).

Comment: why not just use `peekAll`?

Comment: `peekAll` seems like a rough remedy just to get the next record in the store. I was wondering if there's an elegant way.

Comment: you might consider extending store and implementing two methods you have already coded so that they will be available application-wide; because AFAIK there is no built-in way to achieve what you want.